# Unfixable circular dependency

Tags: c++, inheritance

This code gives `error C2504: 'IKeyEvent': base class undefined` on line 3.

```
class IKeyEvent;

class EventDispatcher : private IKeyEvent {
public:
    enum EEActions {
        A_FEW_ACTIONS
    };
private:
    void OnKey(EventDispatcher::EEActions action, char multiplier);
}

class IKeyEvent {
public:
    virtual void OnKey(EventDispatcher::EEActions action, char multiplier) = 0;
};
```

You cannot inherit from a class until it is defined, understandably. But I cannot define `IKeyEvent` until *after* `EventDispatcher` is defined.

I know I can move that `enum` out of the `Event Dispatcher` definition to make it global but this would require refactoring a large portion of the program. Is there any way to have `EventDispatcher` inherit from a class dependent on `EventDispatcher`?

Comment: A base class that requires a type declared in a derived class? Fundamentally something wrong in this OO design?

Comment: @Murali: apparently, this is "just" a refactoring problem; IKeyEvent is being added now, whereas EventDispatcher has been around. I don't think it's fundamentally wrong to add interfaces as you go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My recommendation: move EEActions into the base class - it *is* part of the interface, after all:

```
class IKeyEvent {
public:
    enum EEActions {
        A_FEW_ACTIONS
    };
    virtual void OnKey(EEActions action, char multiplier) = 0;
};

class EventDispatcher : public IKeyEvent {
private:
    void OnKey(EventDispatcher::EEActions action, char multiplier);
};
```

If you then also make the inheritance from IKeyEvent public, you can continue to refer to the enum as `EventDispatcher::EEActions` (despite the enum being defined in the base type).